# Securing client->database game

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, security, phpmyadmin

OK, I am creating a game using JavaScript and HTML5. The variables such as `map`, `x`, `y`, `level`, `exp`, etc are stored in JavaScript to keep track. On my client page, the JavaScript variables are stored to play along with the game. Every 5 seconds, the client page sends a `POST` AJAX call to the `MySQL` database and it successfully updates it.

However a user can easily modify the JavaScript variables and cheat their way in the game. Then once they edit the JavaScript variables, the `POST` grabs that and updates it even though they edited it unethically.

So, how do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Voting to move this question to [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to prevent client-side code from being manipulated by a malevolent party. However, in many cases, there are certain behaviors that could potentially  signal possible abuse.

For instance, if the maximum amount of hit points I can regain via a healing potion is 100 points, and a user suddenly increases by 1000, then you *know* there was abuse. Your strategy should involve putting checks in your code as validation to ensure that the data returned to your application makes sense.

This concept is a lot like what a business application developer might do to make sure that data entered in a web form is validated. If there are certain values that are illegal or that shouldn't be submitted, the server responds with an error message and instructions on what fields need to be filled out.

In your case, it may still be possible for someone to "game the system" at levels below certain thresholds. Start small, and as you analyze the data, you'll find more areas where you can implement this type of validation of your data.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to monitor and analyze the data on the server side - perhaps do some sanity checks such as making sure values aren't out of range or they they only changed by some reasonable amount. The problem with your question is that you can't stop the user from doing what they want, you just have to handle what they give you.

Comment: lol I was going to say "sanity check" but went with a different word :) Your answer hit the mark "you can't stop the user from doing what they want, you just have to handle what they give you."  +1

Comment: @jmort253: Indeed - the sad and difficult truth of web programming.

Comment: I am assuming this is why people don't like making JavaScript games with databases?

Comment: @weka - Anything that is stored on the client side (aka the user's computer) can in most cases be easily manipulated by that person. Not sure if you remember the old [GWBASIC](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/149457/12611) games in the 80's, but since it wasn't compiled code and most of the data was written to text files, you could modify the code yourself or modify the data and make your character stronger. The concept here is similar.

Comment: Where the text file would then be the JavaScript variables...?

Comment: @weka: I suppose that's a good parallel (text file <=> JavaScript vars). What do you want to know though?